# Dont want to associated contact to other objects if status is pending

Tags: apex, validation-rule, lookup-filter, sharing-rule

i want a rule where i dont want to associated contact to other objects if contact status is pending.I am not sure how can i achieve this .any suggestion

Comment: You only want to restrict lookup field on contact or do you also don't want to restrict contact's child record

Comment: means if the contact status is Pending then i dont want to associate this contact to any other entity.

Comment: Like from account if i add relationship and if contact is Pending then it should throw an error

Comment: any suggestion/solution to implement this

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Validation Rule like this, e.g. on Case Object:

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(ContactId)), 
    ISPICKVAL(Contact.Status__c, 'Pending')
)
```

If you want to run this rule only on Contact Person (Lookup) change, you can add one additional check:

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(ContactId)), 
    ISCHANGED(ContactId),
    ISPICKVAL(Contact.Status__c, 'Pending')
)
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Best, Stefan